# mqtt client exceeds timeout and disconnects

Tags: arduino, mqtt

I have installed and use a locally installed mosquitto version 1.5.7 on a raspberry with default settings. The network is used by various devices as mqtt clients and everything seems to work fine. Arduino and esp8266 work with pubsubclient lib.

Now I have introduced a new bare bone Arduino (ATMEGA328P-PU) with a mini W5500 ethernet breakboard as client. Things again work fine, it connects, sets static IP, publishes and subscribes.

However it is unable to keep the connection live after some time. I have tried to play with MQTT_KEEPALIVE, but still PINGREQ & PINGRESP messages are not exchanged between client and broker and so the connection is dropped by broker.

Any suggestions as to what to look for or try? Also is client.loop() responsible for these pings that are not exchanged?

Here is some code:

```
#define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 1000 // keep trying various numbers
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 155);
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 80);
const char* aHostname = "arduino_client";

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
EthernetClient ethClient;

PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }}
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT reconnection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(aHostname)) {
      Serial.print("mqtt status in reconnecting: ");
      Serial.println(client.state());
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
      client.setCallback(callback);
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("Home/Dev1/out","hello world host restarted");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("Home/Dev1/in");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1500);
  client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
  client.setServer(server, 1883);
  client.connect(aHostname);
  
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("mqtt status in setup: ");
    Serial.println(client.state());
    reconnect();
  } else {
    client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
    client.setCallback(callback);
    Serial.print("mqtt status in setup: ");
    Serial.println(client.state()); 
    Serial.println("Dev1 connected at setup");
    client.publish("Home/Dev1/out","hello world front Dev1 started");
    client.subscribe("Home/Dev1/in");
  }
}
void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  
  if(!client.loop())
    client.connect(aHostname);  
}
```

this is the relevant entries from the mosquitto -v produced log:

```
1609683602: Sending SUBACK to <arduino_client>
1609683618: Client <arduino_client> has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1609683618: Socket error on client <arduino_client>, disconnecting.
1609683618: New connection from 192.168.1.155 on port 1883.
1609683618: New client connected from 192.168.1.155 as <arduino_client> (c1, k10).
1609683618: No will message specified.
1609683618: Sending CONNACK to <arduino_client> (0, 0)
1609683618: Received PUBLISH from <arduino_client> (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'Home/Dev1/out', ... (37 bytes))
1609683618: Sending PUBLISH to mosqserver (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'Home/Dev1/in', ... (37 bytes))
...
1609683618: Received SUBSCRIBE from <arduino_client>
1609683618:     Home/Dev1/<arduino_client> (QoS 0)
1609683618: <arduino_client> 0 Home/<arduino client>
1609683618: Sending SUBACK to <arduino_client>
...
1609683634: Client <arduino_client> has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
....
```

If there are any suggestions as to why this occurs or any remedy, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Edit:
I have tried various setSocketTimeout and client.setKeepAlive values. This doesn't solve the issue.  The command client.loop() should have been taking care of PINGREQ & PINGRESP but somehow it doesn't. As a temporary by pass to this issue I have introduced a periodic publish in the loop procedure

```
if ((millis() - LastAnnouncement) > AnnouncementDelay) {
  client.publish("Home/Dev1/out", "device is live");
  LastAnnouncement = millis();
  }
```

Edit2:
Could the above issue be driven by hardware incompatibility? I see that this in

https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient

Compatible Hardware

The library uses the Arduino Ethernet Client api for interacting with the underlying network hardware. This means it Just Works with a growing number of boards and shields

Comment: try to set client.setSocketTimeout. default is 15 seconds

Comment: Thanks Juraj, I tried various combinations of setSocketTimeout and client.setKeepAlive but I see no difference. At the end I get Client <arduino_client> has exceeded timeout, disconnecting, as client and broker doesn't exchange PINGREQ and PINGRESP.